# explicit_plot_order = true and bgcolor Problems?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

if i use `explicit_plot_order = true` in the indicator() / study() syntax of my script for having lines, plots etc. being plotted in the correct z-order, everything works fine.

but as soon as i also use `bgcolor` within my script, the indicator is not showing/updating anymore. Also there is no Error being shown in the debugger.

i cant find any information about an issue between `explicit_plot_order = true` and `bgcolor`... does someone have information ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `bgcolor()` function in a script that uses `explicit_plot_zorder=true` causes a render bug, due to which the indicator cannot be drawn with the `overlay=true` parameter, with `overlay=false` an empty panel of the new indicator will be displayed.

Unfortunately, at the moment there is no workaround for this bug, but the team knows about it and will take it into work as soon as it finishes higher priority tasks. You can submit a report on the platform if you have access to Customer Support and you will be informed when the problem will be fixed.

Comment: thanks for the info. is there any other way except ``explicit_plot_zorder == true`` to solve the problem that lines, plots etc. otherwiese are not drawn in the order they appear in the code ?

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no workaround.
Without using the argument `explicit_plot_zorder = true`, the rendering order will be as described in the [Pine manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Colors.html#z-index).